# using an xml file as a drawable resource

Tags: android, drawable

I have an xml file named off.xml in my drawable directory (is should be a red circle)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
<gradient android:startColor="#FFFF0000" android:endColor="#FFFF0000"
    android:angle="270"/>
```

On my main page I have the following xml...

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip" android:orientation="horizontal">    
<View android:layout_width="40dip"
    android:layout_height="0dip"  android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/off" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I get the error "failed to convert @drawable/off into a drawable.  The red circle does not show.
(I have put a button there to make sure another widget would show)

What is causing this error.  I got the example from another post in this forum that is supposed to work.
thanks, Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems: The closing `</shape>` tag is missing in your drawable and the `layout_height` of your view is 0 or has the wrong orientation.

Comment: I'm not missing the </shape> tag.  there are bugs in this forum that sometimes fail to recognize pasted lines.  Your answer got me thinking about height and weight and turns out I had to put the layout_weight on the linearlayout instead of the view.  I still get the error in Eclipse but the red circle shows.

Answer (score 1):

your @drawable/off layout should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <item><shape android:shape="oval">
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFF00" android:endColor="#FFFF00"
      android:angle="270"/>
    </shape></item>
</selector>
```

Comment: This will not draw a oval shape.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#FFFF0000"
        android:startColor="#FFFF0000" />

</shape>
```

Comment: That's no different from what I have.  (I tried it anyway and still get the same error).